# How to re-position menu icon in responsive nav bar to another side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why does the hamburger button not work when I have my logo inserted? Is it because the height of the image is larger than the navbar? Also how come the two flags cover up the hamburger button, how can I reposition the hamburger button under the 'menu'? I tried to add a media query to the flags @ 800px width to move to the other side (just to test) but it doesn't seem to work. Really hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction, thank you in advance for your help.

[image: Image of the two sized navbars]

http://jsfiddle.net/37uspnk9/
(jquery is linked at the top of html)

```
<nav>
<div class="logo">
<a href="../index.html">
<img src="../images/sblogo.png" alt= "Steven's Logo" img id="logo">
</a>
</div>
<div class="nav">
<ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="artist.html">The Artist</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="languages">
<a href="../it/home.html">
  <img src="../images/italian.jpg" alt= "Cambio Lingua in Italiano" img    id="it">
</a>
<a href="../en/home.html">
  <img src="../images/eng.jpg" alt= "Change Language to English" img id="en">
</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you try adding `position:fixed; top:0; left:0;` to the media query instead of `float: left` ?

Comment: The icons go to the left side, but then they are not confined to the div.

Comment: In that case you will need to limit the size of the images or add them to fixed size container and set [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

Comment: Js fiddle removes script tags from html you need to load it through the settings button on the JavaScript area